# Pear MDB2 not found ~ using PHP with FastCGI

Tags: php, pear, fastcgi

I am getting the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method MDB2_Error::quoteIdentifier()
The full error is this: Fatal error: Call to undefined method MDB2_Error::quoteIdentifier() in /u01/www/givebutton.net/htdocs/lib/OA/Upgrade/VersionController.php on line 51

The environment is this:
PHP 5.3.6-pl0-gentoo (cli) (built: Aug 23 2011 12:37:13)
I am using fastcgi and nginx ...

---

Solution
My problem was that the user was unable to log into the database. I fixed that and poof no more error.  The full code

```
    function init($oDbh='')
    {
        $this->oDbh = $oDbh;
        $this->versionTablename = $oDbh->quoteIdentifier($GLOBALS['_MAX']['CONF']['table']['prefix'].'application_variable', true);
    }
```

As you see $oDbh is a database connection, and the user was not able to login to the database remotely.  Fixed the perms in mysql, and it works.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So MDB2_Error does not have the method `quoteIdentifier`. It is most probably that you tend to get the MDB2 handler but MDB2_Error has returned. Please write some check error code to prevent this.

Comment: It also turns out that I do not have remote access to the db. I will take your advice once I have remote access.

Comment: So that is why you get a MDB2_Error.

Comment: Yes, the db connection is the problem. But you should catch such error in your code. Any way, Fatal Error is not good.

Comment: I agree that the company who wrote this code should have caught that exception :)